# Add a non root user to docker image in eclipse-temurin:17-focal

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

Hi i have created a spring boot application and want to add a non root user to in the docker file.

i was looking at the following
https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/

and this command

```
RUN addgroup -S demo && adduser -S demo -G demo
USER demo
```

but this doesnt work in my docker file which is based on the followin image

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-focal
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080

RUN addgroup -S demo && adduser -S demo -G demo
USER demo

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Error:

```
error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Comment: try `groupadd` and `useradd` instant ? I think this is related to the image. and both options are widely available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image your are using inherits from an Ubuntu distribution, so you have use the right syntax for the failing commands.

You should change:

```
RUN addgroup -S demo && adduser -S demo -G demo
```

Into:

```
RUN addgroup demo 
RUN useradd -g demo demo
```

Comment: I used the following..
RUN addgroup demo
RUN useradd -g demo -u 999 demo
I needed an Id

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documented example uses an Alpine based image, whereas you're using an Ubuntu-based image.

The thing about Alpine is that most commands come from BusyBox, and they don't all follow the exact same syntax as "normal" Linux.

Running a docker build with your Dockerfile clearly shows that the syntax for `adduser/addgroup` is not recognised:

```
17-focal: Pulling from library/eclipse-temurin
0fb668748fc8: Pull complete
b9a37d78e5cc: Pull complete
b08078e9064c: Pull complete
375f5661b61e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7b794fa11b9f7d83af6d0243c97a811b9472062dc404f7676704c5c68578b56b
Status: Downloaded newer image for eclipse-temurin:17-focal
 ---> 7dc6e9a7a5e6
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in b4856b78703d
Removing intermediate container b4856b78703d
 ---> 19ccea563e99
Step 3/6 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in c979018f6080
Removing intermediate container c979018f6080
 ---> 0d9f79b1bcbc
Step 4/6 : RUN addgroup -S demo && adduser -S demo -G demo
 ---> Running in 799ff9057c19
adduser [--home DIR] [--shell SHELL] [--no-create-home] [--uid ID]
[--firstuid ID] [--lastuid ID] [--gecos GECOS] [--ingroup GROUP | --gid ID]
[--disabled-password] [--disabled-login] [--add_extra_groups]
[--encrypt-home] USER
   Add a normal user

adduser --system [--home DIR] [--shell SHELL] [--no-create-home] [--uid ID]
[--gecos GECOS] [--group | --ingroup GROUP | --gid ID] [--disabled-password]
[--disabled-login] [--add_extra_groups] USER
   Add a system user

adduser --group [--gid ID] GROUP
addgroup [--gid ID] GROUP
   Add a user group

addgroup --system [--gid ID] GROUP
   Add a system group

adduser USER GROUP
   Add an existing user to an existing group

general options:
  --quiet | -q      don't give process information to stdout
  --force-badname   allow usernames which do not match the
                    NAME_REGEX[_SYSTEM] configuration variable
  --extrausers      uses extra users as the database
  --help | -h       usage message
  --version | -v    version number and copyright
  --conf | -c FILE  use FILE as configuration file
```

TL;DR:

If you use `eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine` as in your linked documentation, the image builds just fine